# a query that listing all rows and sizes of tables in a Database

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005.My question is;I am looking for a query that  listing all rows and sizes of tables in a Database.

Comment: Shouldn't the title be fixed? You mean row counts and not the rows themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few examples [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20080701045806/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-sql-server-tables-and-their-row-counts.html).

Comment: The link is great, but answers just consisting of a link cf. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers